# Where in Rails should I test cross model logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, model

**The software**

I've got some models in a Rails 3.2 app I created. Roughly speaking the key models are Companies, Products and ReverseIndex. As you probably guessed Companies have multiple Products.  Products have some attribute keywords.

I've created the ReverseIndex which for a given keyword has a list of Product id's.  This way I can do a fast lookup of products by keyword.

The ReverseIndex is updated when the Product is updated using an after_save callback to make sure things stay in sync.

**Question about how to test it with rspec**

I've got the code working but now want to add tests, e.g. making sure that when additional Products are added with the same keywords the appropriate ReverseIndex entry for that keyword is updated with the Product's id and when the Products are removed so is the Product reference from the ReverseIndex entry.

I'm using rspec for testing. This issues relates to models and the logic is in the model class.  However this seems more like system behavior rather than model unit tests. Since it uses after_save and a method in the model it doesn't relate to the controller.

I suspect this is more a question of functional testing--although I'm really trying to confirm basic model behavior. (The catch is I need to create two products first then to do the test add a third product with keywords already used.) Perhaps rspec can (and should) be used) for this and I'm just not familiar enough with the appropriate way to do it.

Any thoughts? How would I do this with rspec or should I use an alternative testing method?

Comment: Sounds like a feature spec to me.